# Multiple Markers does not appear in My Google Map ( v3 )

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, jakarta-ee, google-maps-api-3

i start developing an web application , and i'm using API Google Maps v3
But in my JSP page ! i found a little problem with Markers ! i don't know why it doesn't show up when i load the page

```
var Reservoirs = [
['Place 1', 30.430220, -9.624624],
['Place 2', 30.430254, -9.624254],
['Place 3', 30.430444, -9.624444],
['Place 4', 30.430550, -9.624555],
['Place 5', 30.430550, -9.624774]   

];



    function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {  
                zoom: 17,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.430220, -9.624624),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
          };
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                    mapOptions);

         for (i = 0; i < Reservoirs.length; i++) {   

            createMarker(map, markers[i][1], markers[i][2],markers[i][1], markers[i][0]);
         }
        function createMarker(map, lat ,Lng , name) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, Lng),
                map: map,
                title: name
              });
            }
```

to load the map on the page i used :

```
  <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas"/>
```

So ! what do you think ? where is the problem ? 
Thanks a loot guys !

Comment: you should post the errors that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt define the markers variable, so use Reservoirs. Also your function receives 4 parameters, not 5

```
 for (i = 0; i < Reservoirs.length; i++) {   
    createMarker(map, Reservoirs[i][1], Reservoirs[i][2], Reservoirs[i][0]);
 }
```